# replace iptables with nftables

Tags: iptables, nftables

I am using ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (latest). I want to move to nftables.

How can I remove *iptables* and install *nftables* ?

Comment: If you have in mind to remove iptables package and install nftables package - it is a fundamentals knowledge about package management. Please look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/package-management.html

Comment: thanks for your answer,
does it mean that I just have to remove iptables and install nftables?

Comment: I think that you have a fresh system so why you can't try do it :)? Go ahead ;)